# Implementing Cache manager using Dot Net core

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to DotNet Core. I have created a WEB API using .NEt Core. I have a requirement to implement cache manager in this API. I have a set of record which will get updated once in a day, so i wanted this data stored in an object in memory and call database only if a change has been detected(or at a definite interval, say 3 hrs).
I already tried implementing a logic in my app. but wanted to see if we have a specific packages already available !

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u considered using http cache instead of caching in memory ? In my opinion it's a better solution than caching object in memory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Asp.Net has built-in cache libraries that you can use. They are available in .Net core as well, e.g. you can read about therm [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory). It's a bit too long to describe here, but generally you need to register it in you services:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
    }
}
```

Then you can inject `IMemoryCache` in your services. It requires NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will read about this and will implement

Answer (score 3):

You can use asp.net cache which is available in icrosoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory Nuget Package.Install this package if not available.

Then you need to register cache memory service

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

Consume your cache service into controller

> ```
> public class CacheController : Controller
> {
>     private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
>     public TokenController(IMemoryCache cache) 
>     {
>         _config = config;
>      }
> }
> ```

Use below function to get or set cache data

```
public T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getItemCallBack)
        {
            var item = _cache.Get<T>(cacheKey);
            if (item == null)
            {
                item = getItemCallBack();
                _cache.Set(cacheKey, item, CacheKeysWithOption.CacheOption);
            }
            return item;
        }
```

consume GetOrSet

```
 public IActionResult CacheTryGetValueSet()
    {
        var list = GetOrSet(CacheKeysWithOption.Entry, GetStringList);
        return new JsonResult(list);
    }

    [NonAction]
    public List<String> GetStringList()
    {
        List<String> str = new List<string>()
        {
            "aaaaa",
            "sssdasdas",
            "dasdasdas"
        };
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: CacheKeysWithOption.Entry is just string  key